# jQuery elevate zoom: initiate on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I'm currently using the elevate zoom plugin (http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) to allow zooming into images on hover. The problem I'm having though is the images don't exist on the document load, they're being appended on a click function, and thus the relevant `elevateZoom` function isn't working. 
jSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/3j33gb1y/ 
HTML:

```
<button data-rel="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MUcNEVzLIB8/TrStjvP92kI/AAAAAAAABLI/eK3vb1QMrrw/s1600/slide1-new.png">Click!</button>
<button data-rel="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KDiH65CZ8Hs/TjO9rQbmt9I/AAAAAAAAAfg/HeVV38ckUzk/s1600/3.jpg">Click!</button>
<button data-rel="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pZuNX8uqQhw/TjO9rDvyC8I/AAAAAAAAAfY/N91storzGWc/s1600/2.jpg">Click!</button>
<button data-rel="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-y1cPqvkIts8/TjPDKH1-XDI/AAAAAAAAAgA/l8JbwyqcQvI/s1600/hompimenu.jpg">Click!</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area").html("<img class='test' src='" + imgUrl + "' data-zoom-image='" + imgUrl + "' />").hide().imagesLoaded(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});

$(".test").elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
    cursor: "crosshair"
});
```

As you can see once the `test` image is added to the `#area` container, I want the `elevateZoom` function to come into play and allow people to zoom into the image, not sure if this is possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Move the elevateZoom function into the click handler, so it fires after you add the .html()?

Comment: @martymckeever could you demonstrate in the fiddle? As I had tried that previous to posting the question but it didn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, fiddle is blocked at my office :(

Maybe something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area").html("<img class='test' src='" + imgUrl + "' data-zoom-image='" + imgUrl + "' />").hide().imagesLoaded(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(500, function() {
                $(".test").elevateZoom({
                    zoomType: "inner",
                    cursor: "crosshair"
                });         
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: SO now supports live code snippets. It's a lot like jsfiddle but embedded into your answer.

Comment: This fiddle demonstrates the above: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/3j33gb1y/2/ bit broken but its a starting point anyway.

Comment: @MartyMcKeever Thanks for this btw, worked a charm! I'm trying to replicate with another plugin (to show the client) and I seem to be having a few issues, not sure if you can help with this one (or not): http://jsfiddle.net/y2tdaak2/